# smarty post value issue

Tags: php, smarty

I am using the following code in my add user form:

```
<input type="text" size="50" name="name" 
value="{if isset($post.name)}{$post.name}{elseif isset($details.name)}{$details.name}{/if}" />
```

However the form returns blank in case of any error(PHP validation) but it should show post value(`$post.name`)

Comment: Are you assigning anything to $post.name and $details.name?  I'm assuming they're arrays, so are you assigning anything to $post and $details, for that matter?  Smarty (at least for version 2, not so sure about version 3) doesn't have a $post variable, but it does have $smarty.post

Comment: @GordonM yes i am assigning details in case of editing form, so should i update $post with $smarty.post ?

Comment: Your if statement should indeed work. What happens if you just use `{$post.name}` and `{$details.name}`? Can you included your php assignments?

Answer (score 2):

i have solved the issue mysql, it should be `$smarty.post.name` instead of `$post.name` , thanks for your support.